# Get my current position that triggered a Geofence event

Tags: broadcastreceiver, intentservice, android-geofence

I'm using the Android Location API to register Geofences.

Is it possible to get the user's location that triggered a Geofence-Exit event in the `onHandleIntent()` method of the IntentService or the `onReceive()` method (when using a BroadcastReceiver)?

My current approach is to use `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(String provider)` but I'm not sure if this is reliable, since I have to specify a provider and I don't know which provider my Geofence-Location was based.

The received Intent in `onHandleIntent(Intent int)` or `onReceive(Intent intent)` also doesn't contain any useful location data.

**Long story short:**

Is there a safe/reliable way to the get location that triggered an Geofence event in Android?

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
locationClient.getLastLocation();
```

This function doesn't need provider. It will be probably the best way to get the location, that caused the Exit